# Wordpress do_shortcode with content and shortcodes inside adds shortcode before the content instead of inline

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

It seems that `do_shortcode()` (as well as `apply_filters()`) adds shortcodes in front of the content instead of inline. How could I go about solving this?

To explain: I'm calling something like this inside my post:

```
[add_entry_content]
<p>Some text that needs to be displayed *before* the called list.</p>

[add_display_code_list]<!-- the list-content I add -->[/add_display_code_list]

<p>Some text that needs to be displayed *after* the called list.</p>

[/add_entry_content]
```

My functions.php contains this:

```
// add_entry_content
function add_entry_content_func( $atts, $content = '' ) { ?>

    <div class="entry-content content">
        <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

<?php }
add_shortcode( 'add_entry_content', 'add_entry_content_func' );


// add a function to display the code-list
function add_display_code_list_func( $atts, $content = '' ) { ?>

    <ul>
        <li>Dynamically added 1</li>
        <li>Dynamically added 2</li>
    </ul>

<?php }
add_shortcode( 'add_display_code_list', 'add_display_code_list_func' );
```

### I would expect the parser to display this:

Some text that needs to be displayed *before* the called list.

- Dynamically added 1
- Dynamically added 2

Some text that needs to be displayed *after* the called list.

---

### But it instead displays this (the list is displayed inside the container, but before the text-content):

- Dynamically added 1
- Dynamically added 2

Some text that needs to be displayed *before* the called list.

Some text that needs to be displayed *after* the called list.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are displaying the HTML directly within your shortcode callback. You need to return the HTML back through the shortcode. Think of this like a WordPress filter. This will render your short code and output it wherever in the content it was placed.

```
function add_entry_content_func( $atts, $content = '' ) { 

 $html = '<div class="entry-content content">';
 $html .= apply_filters('the_content', $content);
 $html .= '</div>';

 return $html;
 }
```

Or try this with ob_start();

```
<?php function add_entry_content_func( $atts, $content = '' ) { 

ob_start(); ?>

<div class="entry-content content">
    <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<?php 

 return ob_get_clean();
} ?>
```

Comment: Ok, and how would I achieve that and keep the HTML readable? Using `ob_start()`, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really readable when using a big list like I am using (I concatenated the code to keep it understandable for you here). I tried the `<<<EOT` method, but no dice. Same with `ob_start()`.

Comment: It works fine now, the errors were caused by a bug in Sublime Text. >.< Thanks for the help!

Comment: thank you very much. the first option worked very well.